# How To Setup Virtual Hosts Using XAMPP on localhost:8080

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost, windows-10

when I upgrade my computer to windows 10, I got an error with Xampp and it says my 80 port is being listening by 4 pid. I couldn't find the right service to close. I've searched a lot of web sites but every services that I saw on internet was already close on my computer. So I had to changed my port to localhost:8080. but at this time I couldn't manage to my virtual host works. for any kind of help thank you in advance. Here my some files related with issue : httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf, httpd-ssl.conf and hosts

httpd.conf :

```
Listen 8080
```

httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
##ABC
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\abc  
 ServerName abc.local
 ErrorLog D:\xampp/apache/logs/fiori-error_log
 CustomLog D:\xampp/apache/logs/fiori-access_log common  

   <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\abc">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

httpd-ssl.conf :

```
Listen 443
```

hosts :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1:8080      abc.local
```

Comment: Have you tried visiting http://localhost:8080 in your browser? I don't think you can redirect to other ports via the host file.

Comment: yeap of course I can run my project on localhost:8080. but I would like to run my project like htttp://abc.local cause I'm working with my friends via version control system and I don't wanna always change this line as a localhost:8080.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried visiting `localhost:8080` in your browser?

Please use this URL-

```
abc.local:8080
```

hosts :

```
127.0.0.1      abc.local
```

Hope will help you.